# Delete from a table according to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want to delete records from a table according to another table.
for example this is the base table:

```
table1:
License    Major
9           0012 
8           0015
7           0018 
9           0019
```

and I want to delete items in table1 according to table2:

```
table2:
License    Major 
8           0015
7           0018 
9           0019
```

something like this:

```
delete from table1 
where table1.license=table2.license 
      and table1.major=table2.major
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [DELETE FROM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx) syntax comes in very handy here.

- the second `FROM` clause is a simple `INNER JOIN` selecting all the matching records.
- the first `FROM` clause deletes everything from table1 that matches the second clause.

**SQL Statement**

```
DELETE FROM t1
FROM  table1 t1
      INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.License = t1.License
                              AND t2.Major = t1.Major
```

Answer (score 2):

(Also works)

```
delete table1 
from table2
where table1.license=table2.license and table1.major=table2.major
```